# How does the constructor use my getters and setters without me calling it?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have created a bean in Spring Boot with getters and setters and a parameterized constructor, which is accessed by my controller class. But as soon as I remove the getters and setters, the controller class can't access the variable anymore.

I can't understand how my constructor is using the getter setters even though I never call them.

```
// THIS IS THE BEAN CLASS

package net.javaguides.api.bean;

public class Student {
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Student(int id, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        //we use this keyword to avoid confusion between local variable and instance variable
        //this is used for instance variable
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

```
// THIS IS THE CONTROLLER CLASS
package net.javaguides.api.controller;

import net.javaguides.api.bean.Student;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

//for boilerplate code use @RestController
@RestController
public class StudentController {

    //make a method that returns the properties of the student bean/class/entity
    //it needs to return the object properties so, the return type will be an object type
    //make the method a http get method by using @
    @GetMapping("/studentdetails")
    public Student studentapi(){
        Student st = new Student(
                1,
                "Gurjas",
                "Sahney"
        );
        return st;
    }
}
```

It's not working when I remove the getters and setters, if I remove the getter setter this happens (img posted)
who is calling the getter and setters here?

Comment: "*I  cant understand how my constructor is using the getter setters even though i never call them.*" - The constructor is not using getters and/or setters; [the constructor call works perfectly fine without them (`ideone.com`)](https://ideone.com/mL3VF7). Why do you think it does? Do you have an error message or stack trace? If so, please [edit] the post and add it.

Comment: I am pretty sure the constructor is neither calling the setter nor the getter. Sometimes, however, for mutable objects only, the constructor might return the object's instance before finishing constructing. This might show up as the JSON-Serializer is calling the getter while the constructor still running.

Comment: if i remove the getters and setters, my private variables dont get accessed by the controller class and throws error (wrong type).
With the get sets, its working perfectly, so who is calling them?

Comment: Your object is created as expected BUT the serializer is scanning the object and fields in order to convert it to json/xml. There getter/setter are needed. That's why it does not work without them - even when YOU dont call them explicitly. Same will apply if you want to pass a json-string into a object. You need empty contructor and setters then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return `Student` in `RestController` method and to have the response in `json` format `spring-boot-starter-web` use [Jackson API](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webmvc/mvc-controller/ann-methods/jackson.html) to convert your object to `JSON` and Jackson API needs Getter and Setter methods in order to serialize the `Student` object properly into JSON.

Comment: Hm? Why are the setter called by jackson?

Comment: @Grim in this case just getter methods are invoked but when the OP will have to create a new student by API call Jackson will use noArgsContructor with setters to set the values to fields, this is one way of deserialization that Jackson support and I guess  this is the default one, I think I answered to your question.

Comment: @AndreiLisa I agree, it should only read the getter here. Nevermind